# What does it mean to tell someone to take an implement в зубы and do a task with it?

Tags: идиомы

I recently came across this line:

[*Father to son upon seeing how messy his room is*]

> —Так, пылесос в зубы, и чтоб через час здесь был порядок как в
> казарме!

Then, researching this idiom online further, the only other example I found was this one:

> Дать им лопаты в зубы, и пусть весь огород вскопают.

The only interpretation I can imagine is that (figuratively) putting something between your teeth keeps you from protesting, so perhaps this phrase gives the imperative or the situation a nuance of *just shut up and do it!* (??)

Comment: Another example: https://charter97.org/ru/news/2017/8/11/259401/comments/

Comment: Ещё есть «ноги в руки и вперед». Из той же серии «немедленно и быстро»

Comment: @V.V. And in English, “I want to see asses and elbows!“ 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most common form of this saying is "**тряпку в зубы**", which is in turn a shorter form of "швабру в руки, тряпку в зубы".

The idiom is very flexible, you can bend and stretch it any way you want:
"Швабру в руки, тряпку в зубы, веник в ноги, пылесос подмышку и марш убираться!"

The meaning is that the task must be performed asap, and the person must work in full capacity, figuratively making use of every body part capable of holding an instrument. It's like saying: "Work hard! Every limb must do something towards completing the task!", "If your hands are busy, use your teeth."

Think of pirates with knives in both hands, *and falchion in their teeth*, getting ready to attack the victim ship.

---

Edit:

The meaning "give something to someone to make them shut up", "to brush someone off by giving them something formal but useless" is also possible, especially if the verb "сунуть" is in vicinity.
"Только рот раскроешь, а врач тебе рецепт в зубы -- и будь здоров!"

Comment: I think that the most correct association is the one that comes to mind first. And the very first association is the thought of pirates going on an assault with a dagger in their teeth. The idea that "tool in the teeth" means "shut up" is a thought from someone who is not familiar with Soviet films and cartoons about pirates, or with the cheerful Russian phrase *ноги в руки и вперёд* (feet in hands and forward)

Comment: @Elena ...or from someone who's a non-native and saw other examples of putting something in someone's teeth to keep them from talking:  "Возьму такси, скажу - на курорт. Пятёрку в зубы - что он, в чемоданы лезть будет?"

Comment: @Igor G Now that it's clear to me that it means to put everything into performing a task, I wonder how it comes across: is it pushy, rude, funny, encouraging? In other words, in what contexts do you use this on someone and how does it come across?

Comment: @CocoPop, it's normally very pushy and patronizing but also depends on how you say it.

Comment: @CocoPop, In what context? That's an order, so you must be in position of authority to give that order, otherwise it will come across as rude. And you must be annoyed. My personal preference for this phrase is when giving an order to fix something wrong. Like, you're a student and you've invited your student friends to your place (note: no authority thus far), and they started playing with the snow and made a mess of your nice and clean driveway. Now, that would justify you giving them such order "to take shovels in their teeth and clean that mess right now, before parents come back". [TBC]

Comment: @CocoPop In that case it wouldn't come across as rude, but rather like you're not taking "no" as a responce. You can even make it sound a bit funny.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is colloquial and even somewhat rude, depending on who uses it with regard to whom.
It emphasizes the need for decisiveness in setting out to perform some course of action.

Compare with the English expressions: 'bite the bullet' or 'take a bit between one's teeth'. A bit closer equivalent would be 'put one's nose to the grindstone'.